# Does Commander's Strike reset Reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, reactions

1. You can only use 1 reaction until the start of your next turn.
2. You can only use Sneak Attack once per turn.
3. Sneak attack's benefit is more damage.
4. Reaction's benefit is an extra strike/move while is not your turn.

Therefore, aren't both of them "Turn based benefits"? You can only do them once per turn, and they benefit you in some way.

Using Commander's Strike I can direct my rogue to use her Reaction to Sneak attack again.

> This effectively gives your ally a chance to attack on your turn, which allow for use of **any** turn-based benefits including Sneak Attack.

(emphasis mine)

So my question is:
If she has already used her Reaction and I use Commander's Strike, shouldn't she be able to use it again?

I clearly want it to be so, but what is the truth?

Comment: thanks! Btw welcome and take our [tour] if you have a minute. :)

Comment: Please cite where that quote comes from. It's not in the description of Commander's Strike in the rules.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it doesn't give your ally another Reaction. What you've quoted is a clarification (apparently written by someone on a wiki somewhere) of the last sentence of Commander's Strike. It's not the actual rule to follow. To use Commander's Strike, your ally has to follow this sentence:

> That creature can immediately use its reaction to make one weapon attack, adding the superiority die to the attack's damage roll.

That's all it does: **it lets your ally attack**.

The only reason that Sneak Attack is mentioned is because Sneak Attack can only be done once per turn (not per *round* — per *turn*). Since an attack on your turn is a different turn from the perspective of your rogue ally, they can apply Sneak Attack damage to this new single attack.

A single attack doesn't give a new Reaction, unlike how it allows a new Sneak Attack bonus. Nor are Reactions “turn benefits”. Instead, Reactions are a type of action, which are limited *per **round*** to 1 for each character. In other words, a character can take as many Reactions as they want, so long as 1) they have an ability to use that counts as a Reaction, and 2) they don't exceed the round limit for Reactions (which is almost always 1).

Getting another attack on someone else's *turn* doesn't increase your ally's Reaction limit.

Answer (score 6):

## Each character has 1 reaction per round, *Commander's Strike* doesn't give you another one

Every character in combat has 1 reaction per round. From the PHB:

> When you take a reaction, you can't take another one
> until the start of your next turn.

So if your rogue has already used his reaction, he can't use another one to take advantage of the *Commander's Strike* because he doesn't have one left to use.

That being said, if the rogue *hasn't* already used his reaction he could use it then and, yes, he can sneak attack again (assuming he meets the requirements for it) since it is no longer his turn, and sneak attack is a once-per-turn thing.

Comment: "assuming he has advantage" - or assuming he has otherwise met the requirements for Sneak Attack (which can vary depending on the rogue's subclass).

Answer (score 3):

### No, you cannot get another reaction using Commander's Strike

Between the time when your turn ends and the next time your turn begins, you have access to (usually, baring some outside effect) one action, potentially one bonus action (if there's some way to use it), and potentially one reaction (if there's some way to use it).

Reactions are *usually* taken during **someone else's turn** (though, you are *allowed* to take a reaction on your turn if the appropriate trigger occurs).

With that said, Sneak Attack can only occur once per "turn", so if Commander's Strike is used to allow a rogue to use their one reaction on an attack, they could potentially get another Sneak Attack, because it wasn't their turn.

If the rogue already used their reaction on something else, they cannot manifest one just because a character used some ability, unless that ability specifically grants another reaction.

Comment: It is important to note that a Reaction can be taken during your turn if the trigger allows it: "*A reaction
is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which
can occur on your turn or on someone else’s.*" (PHB 190) This is important because a tweet from [Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/05/29/does-the-movement-from-dissonant-whispers-provoke-opportunity-attacks/) clarifies that Dissonant Whispers *does* provoke an Attack of Opportunity if the creature was within Melee range of you.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath, hence why I said "usually", but I'll clear it up.